# Why can't I implement a move constructor with a reference variable?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

The way move constructors are usually implemented is like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    int *ptr;
    Test() {
    }
    Test(Test&& t) {
        ptr = t.ptr;
        t.ptr = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t = Test(Test());
    return 0;
}
```

Buy why can't we implement them like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    int *ptr;
    Test() {
    }
    Test(Test& t) {
        ptr = t.ptr;
        t.ptr = nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t = Test(Test());
    return 0;
}
```

The second piece of code seems to run just fine. I don't understand why we cannot do it like that.

Comment: `Test t = Test(Test());` is equivalent to `Test t = Test();` in C++17 (*"copy elision"*).

Comment: @Jarod42 Which is, in turn, equivalent to `Test t;`

Comment: `Test(Test& t)` would be a copy constructor (even without `const`).

Comment: Neither snippet tries to run a move constructor in C++17. Try `Test a, b(std::move(a));`.

Comment: Take a look at what [happens](https://godbolt.org/z/rTxvqWbaj) if I use an older C++ standard and turn off copy elision. Your signature simply _is not_ a move constructor.

Comment: @NathanPierson You don't even have to turn off copy elision. It's a hard error before C++17

Comment: @Jarod42 And `Test t = Test();` is equivalent to `Test t;` :-)

Comment: What's the motivation behind this question? Both `Test(Test&& t)` and `Test(Test& t)` are valid signatures for constructors. The former is named "move constructor", while the latter is named "copy constructor". It's not really a question of "can" vs. "cannot", but a matter of how the terminology is defined.

Comment: *The way move constructors are usually implemented is like this...* I'd implement it like this: `Test(Test&& from) : ptr{exchange(from.ptr, nullptr)} { }`

Answer (score 8):

You cannot bind a non-`const` lvalue reference to an rvalue (that is, neither prvalues nor xvalues can be used), so your special constructor cannot be used with temporaries or in move operations.

```cpp
Test t;
Test t2(std::move(t)); // error: tries to bind a non-const& to an xvalue
```

In your case, it compiles because you are using C++17 or later in which `Test t = Test(Test());` is equivalent to `Test t;` because of mandatory copy/move elision<sup>1)</sup>. Your special constructor is simply not used. Only the default constructor is.

---

<sup>1)</sup> `t` is initialized by a prvalue of the same type, so `= T(...)` initializes `t` directly. See [Copy elision on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly do that. Users of your code (including your future self) will curse you.

```
Test t1;
Test t2(t1); // Surprise! t1 no longer holds a valid pointer
```

With a move constructor that takes an rvalue you have to say that you want to blow it up:

```
Test t1;
Test t2(std::move(t1)); // Okay, says what it does
```